# MVC5 Referencing Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a table such as this:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CaptainId { get; set; }
    public string CoCaptainId { get; set; }
    public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a table such as this:

```
public class TeamMember
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string GameDisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Joined { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 questions that I do not understand around EF 6 and MVC5.

1) How do I reference my Id field in Team table.  Do I set TeamId inside TeamMember as a string or as a Guid?  I understand I will need to set the attribute `[ForeignKey("Team")]` however I still do not understand how to properly reference to it in the code because whenever I need to do any type of comparison, I always have to type `.ToString()` on the Guid to be able to get the value to compare against another string value.

2) My TeamMember also has an Id, and this Id references User in Identity framework.  How should I reference that one, the Id is meant to be a foreign key that references the Id in User table, but I do not know how to properly reference that one either, is it string like I did it or is it Guid or something else?

EDIT:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CaptainId { get; set; }
    public Guid CoCaptainId { get; set; }
}

public class TeamMember
{
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
}

public class Member : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string CustomUrl { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<Member> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Member>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("MemberClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MemberRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("MemberLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().ToTable("Member");
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Error that I get:

```
var user = new Member { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, CustomUrl = model.CustomUrl, Alias = model.Alias};
var team = new Team {CaptainId = user.Id, Created = currentTime, IsSingleMember = true};
```

`CaptainId = user.Id gives an error:`

`Cannot convert source type 'string' to target type 'System.Guid'`

Comment: Should probably try to be more consistent; if you're going to use Guid/uniqueidentifier as the primary key on one table, use the same column type on the other tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same type, which is `Guid`.

```
public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
```

Also, you need to keep a `virtual Team` property of `Team` type in your `TeamMember` model. Also typically `int` or `long` or `Guid` are the types used for primary key of a table. `string` might not be a good idea as you need to execute your custom code to generate a string which does not exist in the table.

This will generate the 2 tables with proper foreign key relationships.

```
public class Team
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CaptainId { get; set; }
    public string CoCaptainId { get; set; }
    public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
}
public class TeamMember
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string GameDisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Joined { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { set; get; }
}
```

You do not need to do a `ToString()` conversion now for comparison. You can do `YourGuid1==YourGuid2` expression

Comment: CaptainId, CoCaptainId are both foreign keys to User table, should I make those Guid as well?  This is inside Team Table.  I don't know what Identity will return back as.

Comment: I also noticed that you are missing a foreign key reference in team member?  Is this not required?

Comment: Yes. You should change those foreign key columns to long/int/guid and add the relevant virtual properties as well. As long as you have the `virtual Team` in team member, it will create the proper foreign key (by convention).

Comment: Thanks for all your help Shyju!  I have tried it your way but few things do not add up.  I have edited my question to show you what I have right now for Member, for Team, and for TeamMember.  When I try to assign Id value from Member class into MemberId I get an error saying it cant convert string to Guid.  For this reason I believe I should leave Captain as string as oppose to Guid.  Is this correct or should I be casting a .ToString to convert this?

Comment: I also just included the sample code that produces the error with the error message.

Comment: @Bagzli References have to be the same types as the properties they refer to. That's non-negotiable. If you want to assign a value to them from string, you have to parse the string into the appropriate type first.

Comment: @GertArnold I understand that, but from what I understood is that Shyju was telling me that Captain id should also be Guid, but Identity has it as string.  I am of the opinions that I should change CaptainId to string and CoCaptainId to string, however I do not know how this affects the mapping.  Is this a correct thing to do?